# How to write this multi-line statement in PowerShell 3.0

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to write this in PowerShell:

> cspack $a/ServiceDefinition.csdef /role:$b;$c /rolePropertiesFile:$a.$b;c$ /sites:$a;$b;$c /out:$out

But it looks like PowerShell needs this statement broken up which I'm having trouble with.

I get error/s like:

> You must provide a value expression on the right hand side of the '/' operator

So how do I call an EXE file and provide a multi-line / switch argument in PowerShell If I do the following?

```
cspack.exe $a/ServiceDefinition.csdef `
/role:$b;$c `  (place backtick on the end)
/rolePropertiesFile:$a.$b;c$ (powershell complains on this line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error about the `/` operator usually indicates that PowerShell is not treating the command as a command line; prefix a `&` to force it to do so.  Note you'll also need to use `.\cspack` if `cspack` is in the current directory.  PowerShell will also treat semicolons as statement terminators, so you'll want to surround each parameter with quotes to prevent that.

```
& cspack "$a/ServiceDefinition.csdef" "/role:$b;$c" "/rolePropertiesFile:$a.$b;c$" "/sites:$a;$b;$c" "/out:$out"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the semi-colons as that is the statement separator in PowerShell.  After each `;` PowerShell thinks it is executing a new command. Try this:

```
cspack $a/ServiceDefinition.csdef /role:$b`;$c /rolePropertiesFile:$a.$b`;c$ /sites:$a`;$b`;$c /out:$out
```